# fetching not with custom primary id in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have created a table in which the primary id have to customize id product_id like

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    product_id = models.BigIntegerField(auto_created = True,primary_key = True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

after creating the record I want to get the id of the latest record but when I retrieve the data with this id getting `None`

```
product = Product.objects.create(name=name, ref=ref, number=number)
print(product.product_id)
```

`product.product_id` id getting null
Pleae give me a solution to why this is happening.

Comment: You should use an `AutoField` or `BigAutoField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will set the primary key of an `AutoField` or `BigAutoField`, given that the database supports returning the assigned primary key.

You thus should rewrite the model to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    # …
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Django does not know what the primary key (pk) of the object is going to be before the object is saved in the database.

That is because Django does not determine the value of the pk for the incoming object, your database does. In order to get the pk, you first have to save the object then retrive its pk.